# Redirect only stdout to /dev/null

Tags: node.js, bash, stdout, stdio

I haven't yet mastered the weird shell stdio redirection thing yet.

I want to run npm install but redirect stdout so I don't have to see all of that. (I still want to capture stderr in the terminal, I just don't want to see stdout).

```
npm install -D suman 1> /dev/null
```

This doesn't seem to work.

What is the correct syntax (and possibly, why) to use to only redirect stdout to `/dev/null`?

Comment: "it's probably being printed to stdout by the npm command", you mean stderr, not stdout...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "This doesn't seem to work."?

The syntax you're using is correct. If you're still seeing output that you're not expecting, it's probably being printed to stderr by the npm command.

Try this: `npm install -D suman >npm.out 2>npm.err`; that should show you exactly what's being printed where.

Comment: Quite right; I've posted a corrected comment.

Comment: thanks got it, yeah, I will experiment with my own script instead of npm and see

Comment: What I meant is that I think you're mistaken about what `npm` is writing to stdout vs. stderr. The command I suggested will show you what `npm` is doing. You still haven't explained what you mean by "This doesn't seem to work".

Comment: No I get it, @MTilsted answer is correct, NPM seems to destroy my world by writing non-warnings and non-errors to stderr, killing me right now

Comment: If you could comment on the difference between 1> and > in the OP vs the answer, that would be helpful

Comment: As I already said, `1>` and `>` mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Ok cool, I wish they didn't mean the same thing :) Shorthand is the worst invention ever.

Comment: thanks for your help, btw, if npm is really writing this stuff to stderr, I am going to be mad

Comment: @AlexanderMills: Many commands write things other than warnings and errors to stderr; for example, `curl` will send its status (including drawing the download progress bar) to stderr. This is because it sends the downloaded web file to stdout, and it's very important that nothing else get mixed in with that. This is the case for many other commands: they send one specific thing to stdout, and *everything else* to stderr.

Comment: yeah this is true

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`npm install -D suman > /dev/null` should do it. (It is standard for the redirect, only to redirect stdout)

Comment: That does exactly the same thing as the command in the question; `> /dev/null` is equivalent to `1> /dev/null`.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: It's the right syntax, but you already said it didn't work.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: Please read and reply to the comment I posted on the question.

Comment: I think it's because NPM writes most of their crap to stderr, major design flaw. So redirecting stdout to /dev/dull doesn't actually get rid of anything.